# Can't connect to Redis OM from Node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm trying to connect to Redis cloud database.
Documentation provides following code:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis'
import { Client } from 'redis-om'

(async function() {

  let redis = createClient('redis://localhost:6379')
  let client = await new Client().use(redis)

  await redis.set('foo', 'bar')
  let value = await client.execute(['GET', 'foo'])
})()
```

For cloud DB I should use Redis Connection Strings (I suppose):
`redis://username:password@host:port` instead of `redis://localhost:6379`.

In Redis console my DB has public endpoint, which includes `host` and `port`:
`redis-port_number.host_data_code:port_number`.

In this console I also have DB name and DB password. Apart from that I have `username` and it's `password` at Data Access Control (DAC) tab.

So getting back to Connection String `redis://username:password@host:port`:
what data should be placed instead of username and password, host and port? I tried different combinations but got connection error.

For instance:
`redis://DAC_admin:DAC_admin_password@data_base_endpoint_with_host_and_url`.
Should I place DB name and password instead of DAC? It didn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation—which I wrote—is incorrect. A patch is forthcoming. The correct code should be:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis'
import { Client } from 'redis-om'

(async function() {

  let redis = createClient('redis://localhost:6379')
  await redis.connect()
  let client = await new Client().use(redis)

  await redis.set('foo', 'bar')
  let value = await client.execute(['GET', 'foo'])
})()
```

Comment: But I want to connect to Redis Cloud DB. That was the point of my question

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. You should be able to use either of these, assuming that your DAC user has permissions to access the database. For the default user, there is no username to specify. So you URL would be:

redis://:password@hostname:port

For the DAC, what you specified should work. Maybe you've not granted the user you created access to that particular database?